# How to disable PHP's ini_set for specific configuration options?

Tags: php, chroot

I'm running a setup with PHP 5.3.8 and use php-fpm with its chroot functionality to separate multiple customers. So each customer has it's own chrooted PHP-environment, which is quite fine.

I now want to disallow that a customer can change the `memory_limit` of his PHP-instance by using `ini_set`. On the other hand I don't want to disable `ini_set` completely. So I'm searching for a possibility to disable the possibility to set specific PHP configuration options (like `memory_limit`) via `ini_set`.

Does somebody know how to achieve that?

Comment: Look into [suhosin](http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/) it is well suited to hardening PHP for hosting environments, including preventing alteration of the memory_limit

Answer (score 1):

You can't, without patching the PHP source code.

Answer (score 1):

As cyberx86 noted in his comment, it's at least possible with suhosin to disallow changes to `memory_limit` during runtime. The configuration option for that in suhoshin is called `suhosin.memory_limit`.

Answer (score 1):

For Apache, you can set something like the following in httpd.conf:

```
php_admin_value memory_limit 2G
```

and that will make pointless any line in a script like:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '4096M');
```

You can read more [here](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php).

HTH